# spring batch jpa with many to one relation

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm trying to import csv file to populate my database.

```
City {
  String name;
  @ManyToOne
  Country country;
  String State;
  double area;
}
Country {
  String name;
  String code;
}
```

Here is a csv record example:

```
city_name  state  country_name  country_code  area  garbage_data
  Toronto   Ontario   Canada       CA        205.3     .....
```

I use spring data JPA to handle database transactions.
Here is my spring batch code:

```
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<City> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<City> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("Hotel-Cities.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<City>() {
            {
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                    {
                        setIncludedFields(new int[]{0,1,2,3,4});
                    }
                });
                **//what to do here to map city that includes country?**
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<City>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(City.class);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return reader;
    }
```

Since city has many-to-one relationship with country, where should I do something like `dao.save(country);city.set(country); dao.save(city);`

From what I learned, reader reads csv columns and map value to object, writer writes object to database. I still don't know how to resolve entity reference.

PS. I get type mismatch error when convert string to double, how to resolve it?

Comment: Tried to make use of cascade type in your relationship?  Though I am not sure how will JPA/Hibernate deal with already-existing entity though.

Comment: @AdrianShum so in the writer  I can directly call `dao.save(city)` ?

Comment: Supposedly yes.  However as you are creating a new instance of Country for each City (as it is a Many-to-one), I am not clear if it will works well.  In worst case, you can just inject your `CountryRepository` into the reader, get the `Country` and use it as relationship, or create it if it is not in DB yet.

Comment: @AdrianShum Do you know why my reader does not skip header line? It will try to create city using {city_name  state  country_name  country_code  area}.

Comment: @AdrianShum Where should I inject repository? I tried using it in FieldSetMapper, but `@Autowire` is not working.

Comment: In your reader of course.  Your `FieldSetMapper` is not managed by Spring